# How can I align this equations in enumitem?

Tags: align

This is my code.

```
   \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
        \item \begin{align*}
            \left(\sqrt{2}\, x+3 y\right)^{5}&=\left(\sqrt{2}\cdot x\right)^{5}+5\cdot \left(\sqrt{2}\cdot x\right)^{4}\cdot \left(3 y\right)+10\cdot \left(\sqrt{2}\cdot x\right)^{3}\cdot \left(3 y\right)^{2}+10\cdot \left(\sqrt{2}\cdot x\right)^{2}\cdot \left(3 y\right)^{3}+5\cdot \left(\sqrt{2}\cdot x\right)\cdot \left(3 y\right)^{4}+\left(3 y\right)^{5}
            \\
            &=4 \sqrt{2}\, x^{5}+60 y \,x^{4}+180 \sqrt{2}\, y^{2} x^{3}+540 y^{3} x^{2}+405 \sqrt{2}\, y^{4} x+243 y^{5}
        \end{align*}
        \item \begin{align*}
            \left(\sqrt{3}\, x-t\right)^{5}&=\left(\sqrt{3}\cdot x\right)^{5}+5\cdot \left(\sqrt{3}\cdot x\right)^{4}\cdot \left(-t\right)+10\cdot \left(\sqrt{3}\cdot x\right)^{3}\cdot \left(-t\right)^{2}+10\cdot \left(\sqrt{3}\cdot x\right)^{2}\cdot \left(-t\right)^{3}+5\cdot \left(\sqrt{3}\cdot x\right)\cdot \left(-t\right)^{4}-t^{5}
            \\
            &=9 \sqrt{3}\, x^{5}-45 t \,x^{4}+30 \sqrt{3}\, t^{2} x^{3}-30 t^{3} x^{2}+5 \sqrt{3}\, t^{4} x-t^{5}
        \end{align*}
        \item   \begin{align*}
            \left(\frac{x}{3}-\sqrt{5}\right)^{5}&=\left(\frac{1}{3}\cdot x\right)^{5}+5\cdot \left(\frac{1}{3}\cdot x\right)^{4}\cdot \left(-\sqrt{5}\right)+10\cdot \left(\frac{1}{3}\cdot x\right)^{3}\cdot \left(-\sqrt{5}\right)^{2}+10\cdot \left(\frac{1}{3}\cdot x\right)^{2}\cdot \left(-\sqrt{5}\right)^{3}+5\cdot \left(\frac{1}{3}\cdot x\right)\cdot \left(-\sqrt{5}\right)^{4}+\left(-\sqrt{5}\right)^{5}
            \\
            &=\dfrac{x^{5}}{243}-\frac{5 \sqrt{5}\, x^{4}}{81}+\frac{50 x^{3}}{27}-\frac{50 \sqrt{5}\, x^{2}}{9}+\frac{125 x}{3}-25 \sqrt{5}
        \end{align*}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: The list `left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm` may be expressed more parsimoniously as `margin=2cm`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

Note that I've gotten rid of all 32 [!] `\left`-`\right` pairs and all 39 `\cdot` directives. Note also that I had to introduce additiona line breaks since the expansions of the fifth-order polynomials are too long to fit comfortably in one line.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'alignat' environment
\newcommand\myitem{\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi)}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{enumi}{0}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    &\myitem& \qquad
    (\sqrt{2}\, x+3 y)^5
    &=(\sqrt{2} x)^5+5 (\sqrt{2} x)^4 (3 y)+10 (\sqrt{2} x)^3 (3 y)^2+10 (\sqrt{2} x)^2 (3 y)^3\\
    &&&\qquad +5 (\sqrt{2} x) (3 y)^4+(3 y)^5\\[0.5\jot]
    &&&= 4 \sqrt{2}\, x^5+60 y \,x^4+180 \sqrt{2}\, y^2 x^3+540 y^3 x^2+405 \sqrt{2}\, y^4 x+243 y^5 \\[4\jot]
    &\myitem&
    (\sqrt{3}\, x-t)^5
    &=(\sqrt{3} x)^5+5 (\sqrt{3} x)^4 (-t)+10 (\sqrt{3} x)^3 (-t)^2+10 (\sqrt{3} x)^2 (-t)^3\\
    &&&\qquad+5 (\sqrt{3} x) (-t)^4-t^5 \\[0.5\jot]
    &&&=9 \sqrt{3}\, x^5-45 t \,x^4+30 \sqrt{3}\, t^2 x^3-30 t^3 x^2+5 \sqrt{3}\, t^4 x-t^5\\[4\jot]
    &\myitem& 
    (\tfrac13 x-\sqrt{5}\,)^5
    &=(\tfrac13 x)^5+5 (\tfrac13 x)^4 (-\sqrt{5}\,)+10 (\tfrac13 x)^3 (-\sqrt{5}\,)^2+10 (\tfrac13 x)^2 (-\sqrt{5}\,)^3\\
    &&&\qquad+5 (\tfrac13 x) (-\sqrt{5}\,)^4+(-\sqrt{5}\,)^5 \\[0.5\jot]
    &&&=\tfrac{1}{243}x^5-\tfrac{5 \sqrt{5}}{81}x^4+\tfrac{50}{27}x^3 -\tfrac{50\sqrt{5}}{9}x^2+\tfrac{125}{3}x -25\sqrt{5}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for clean my code.

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter - You're most welcome. :-) I've gone ahead and simplified the code for typesetting the material to the left of the `=` symbols a bit more, by switching from an `align*` to an `alignat*` environment.

Comment: @Mico I use `\usepackage{fouriernc}` it seems `tfrac` too small

Comment: @ThuyNguyen - I chose to use `\tfrac` instead of `\frac` (or, equivalently, `\dfrac`) in item 3 to give it an appearance that's roughly similar to that of the first two items. If that's not important, then by all means don't use `\tfrac`. Incidentally, is it `\tfrac`  that's too small? Or, rather, could it be that the round parentheses that surround the `\tfrac` terms that are too small?

Comment: @Mico I feel both.

Comment: @ThuyNguyen - I'm not sure I understand the purpose of your comments. Are you suggesting I should do something differently? If so, what? Please be specific.

Answer (score 5):

I removed all the `\left` and `\right` instructions, besides all `\cdot` commands that are not used in algebra except when really needed to avoid ambiguities.

I also fixed some inconsistencies in spacing, leaving `\,` only between a square root and a variable or simple parenthesis. Note also the `\!` command in the exponents to the large parentheses.

I chose `flalign` in order to have the list numbers at the left margin. As a final touch, I observed the widest line and added `\qquad` at the end thereof, so the equation block is moved to the left, nearer the numbers.

Notice the 1ex spacing between the lines with an equal sign pertaining to the same equation and the 3ex between items. This helps the reader by giving more visual clues.

The `showframe` option should be removed for the final production, as it is used for showing the margins of the text block.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
\text{1)}&&
  (\sqrt{2}\,x + 3y)^{5} &= 
    (\sqrt{2}\,x)^{5}
    +5(\sqrt{2}\,x)^{4}(3y)
    +10(\sqrt{2}\,x)^{3}(3y)^{2}
    +10(\sqrt{2}\,x)^{2}(3y)^{3}
\\&&&\qquad
    +5(\sqrt{2}\,x)(3y)^{4}
    +(3y)^{5}
&\\[1ex]
&&&=4\sqrt{2}\,x^{5}
   +60yx^{4}+180\sqrt{2}\,y^{2}x^{3}
   +540y^{3}x^{2}
   +405\sqrt{2}\, y^{4}x
   +243 y^{5}
&\\[3ex]
\text{2)}&&
  (\sqrt{3}\,x - t)^{5} &=
    (\sqrt{3}\,x)^{5}
    +5(\sqrt{3}\,x)^{4}(-t)
    +10(\sqrt{3}\,x)^{3}(-t)^{2}
    +10(\sqrt{3}\,x)^{2}(-t)^{3}
\\&&&\qquad
    +5(\sqrt{3}\,x)(-t)^{4}
    +(-t)^{5}
&\\[1ex]
&&&=9\sqrt{3}\,x^{5}
   -45tx^{4}
   +30\sqrt{3}\,t^{2}x^{3}
   -30 t^{3}x^{2}
   +5\sqrt{3}\,t^{4}x-t^{5}
&\\[3ex]
\text{3)}&&
  \biggl(\frac{x}{3}-\sqrt{5}\biggr)^{\!5} &=
    \biggl(\frac{1}{3}x\biggr)^{\!5}
    +5\biggl(\frac{1}{3}\,x\biggr)^{\!4}(-\sqrt{5}\,)
    +10\biggl(\frac{1}{3}x\biggr)^{\!3}(-\sqrt{5}\,)^{2}
    +10\biggl(\frac{1}{3}x\biggr)^{\!2}(-\sqrt{5}\,)^{3}
\qquad% <--- move a bit to the left
\\&&&\qquad
    +5\biggl(\frac{1}{3}x\biggr)(-\sqrt{5}\,)^{4}
    +(-\sqrt{5}\,)^{5}
&\\[1ex]
&&&=\frac{x^{5}}{243}
   -\frac{5 \sqrt{5}\, x^{4}}{81}
   +\frac{50 x^{3}}{27}
   -\frac{50 \sqrt{5}\, x^{2}}{9}
   +\frac{125 x}{3}
   -25 \sqrt{5}
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `fouriernc` you'd need some changes; in particular `\bigg` is too small and `\Bigg` is needed. The first two equations fit in the line, but not the last one.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
\text{1)}&&
  (\sqrt{2}\,x + 3y)^{5} &= 
    (\sqrt{2}\,x)^{5}
    +5(\sqrt{2}\,x)^{4}(3y)
    +10(\sqrt{2}\,x)^{3}(3y)^{2}
    +10(\sqrt{2}\,x)^{2}(3y)^{3}
    +5(\sqrt{2}\,x)(3y)^{4}
    +(3y)^{5}
&\\[1ex]
&&&=4\sqrt{2}\,x^{5}
   +60yx^{4}+180\sqrt{2}\,y^{2}x^{3}
   +540y^{3}x^{2}
   +405\sqrt{2}\, y^{4}x
   +243 y^{5}
&\\[3ex]
\text{2)}&&
  (\sqrt{3}\,x - t)^{5} &=
    (\sqrt{3}\,x)^{5}
    +5(\sqrt{3}\,x)^{4}(-t)
    +10(\sqrt{3}\,x)^{3}(-t)^{2}
    +10(\sqrt{3}\,x)^{2}(-t)^{3}
    +5(\sqrt{3}\,x)(-t)^{4}
    +(-t)^{5}
&\\[1ex]
&&&=9\sqrt{3}\,x^{5}
   -45tx^{4}
   +30\sqrt{3}\,t^{2}x^{3}
   -30 t^{3}x^{2}
   +5\sqrt{3}\,t^{4}x-t^{5}
&\\[3ex]
\text{3)}&&
  \Biggl(\frac{x}{3}-\sqrt{5}\Biggr)^{\!5} &=
    \Biggl(\frac{1}{3}x\Biggr)^{\!5}
    +5\Biggl(\frac{1}{3}\,x\Biggr)^{\!4}(-\sqrt{5}\,)
    +10\Biggl(\frac{1}{3}x\Biggr)^{\!3}(-\sqrt{5}\,)^{2}
    +10\Biggl(\frac{1}{3}x\Biggr)^{\!2}(-\sqrt{5}\,)^{3}
\\&&&\qquad
    +5\Biggl(\frac{1}{3}x\Biggr)(-\sqrt{5}\,)^{4}
    +(-\sqrt{5}\,)^{5}
&\\[1ex]
&&&=\frac{x^{5}}{243}
   -\frac{5 \sqrt{5}\, x^{4}}{81}
   +\frac{50 x^{3}}{27}
   -\frac{50 \sqrt{5}\, x^{2}}{9}
   +\frac{125 x}{3}
   -25 \sqrt{5}
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Just in case any readers get confused: The use of the `fouriernc` font package is not something the OP indicated being interested in. Rather, it's user @ThuyNguyen who indicated interest in this, in a comment below my answer. :-)